Can 'where' replace 'in which' in this sentence?

I earned little money at a local farm, where I learned a lot of things.
I earned little money at a local farm, in which I learned a lot of things.

If not, please let me know why in which cannot replace where in the sentence.

You can use where or which, but you need to choose the right preposition. In which means I learned a lot of things in the farm. I'd be more likely to say at the farm. (Hence at which I learned...) But that repeats the preposition at, which is why your first version sounds more natural to me.

Adding to what Peter has said: "in which" is being used in your sample sentence to introduce a restrictive clause (which isn't what you intend), so that comma should be deleted. (In contrast, in That local farm, in which I learned a lot of things, was where I earned a little pocket money, "in which" introduces a nonrestrictive clause.)

Following on Ryang's comment - you probably want to say a little money. Saying that you earned 'little money" implies 'not very much', as though you were complaining that you didn't earn more.

I'm voting to close as this is just a proof-reading question. There is no point of English grammar in the question.

I'd go for "on a farm", not "at" or "in". That's surely standard at least in the UK.

@StuartF I don't think there's anything regional about it. I was going to say in my answer that "at" could maybe have an outside chance, being at least better than "in," but ngrams suggests otherwise.

By the way, the edit history shows that you might have some confusion about "replace." When I say "A replaces B," I mean that A takes B's place. I think in your edit to the title it got reversed.

"In which" is a poor choice simply because we don't usually use "in" for farms. For instance, you don't "work in a farm" and a cow doesn't "live in a farm." A much more common preposition is "on a farm."
